# Using socket io on webserver

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webserver

I used socket.io on localhost:3000 for several tests. Now i tried getting it to work online for an hour but I’m making no progress.

server.js

```
const http = require('http').createServer()
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
io.on('connection' (socket) => {
        socket.on('start_session', (data) => {
                console.log('hey there')
        })
})
```

app.js

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
socket.emit('start_session', session_id)
```

The server.js is running on a server, it’s in the same folder as my index.html and app.js, on my own device it’s working perfectly fine

What am I missing? Can this even be archived with using localhost? I searched for alternatives but it’s always localhost.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The path to the socket.io.js file is also not working, how do I find that out? Tried the whereis command, but that didn’t help.